# Why !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId) is not working anymore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The below code used to work for me when I tested it few months back.Now I cant see it working.The hit gets registered behind the UI always and the model that I placed using the UNITYARHIT example scene gets placed behind the UI.

```
#else
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
            {
                var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                    x = screenPosition.x,
                    y = screenPosition.y
                };

                // prioritize reults types
                ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingGeometry,
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                    // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                   // ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedHorizontalPlane, 
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedVerticalPlane, 
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                }; 

                foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                {
                    if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endif
```

The below script I have added to the model to swipe to rotate.On touch the model moves awkwardly.It moves along the plane and rotates.Once the plane gets detected do I have to turn off the plane detection to make the rotation with swipe working?

```
if(Input.touchCount==2  &&  Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;


        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up ,touchDeltaPosition.x * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
       // transform.Rotate(Vector3.right,touchDeltaPosition.y * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);


    }
```

Comment: did you removed the event system in the scene? or is there no raycaster for the canvas?

Comment: @Vampirasu I have EventSystem in my heirarchy and Graphic raycaster in Canvas